# CSS not applied in OSX application using WebView

Tags: html, css, swift, macos, webview

Working on a custom application in Swift that uses a WebView.  As part of loading content into the WebView there is a static loading HTML screen.  The HTML specifies a CSS file to use which is not applied.  The HTML is quite simple...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>css3-loader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loader.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loaders">
        <div class="loader-container circle-pulse-multiple">
            <div class="loader">
                <div class="circle-1"></div>
                <div class="circle-2"></div>
                <div class="circle-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load the HTML page on it's own all is well but when used within the context of a WebView things do not seem to work.  If I embed the CSS directly into the HTML page this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Where is your HTML file located: main bundle, a folder on your hard drive? Does `loader.css` reside in the same folder?

Comment: @CodeDifferent hey yeah sorry should've specified both html and css files are in the same folder and in the main bundle I've verified they are both included in the final application package.

Comment: I tried embedding the CSS directly into the HTML to avoid any path issues and this doesn't seem to affect anything.  The beginning frame of the animation shows but then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue with the particular CSS directives I'm using.  I tried a much simpler CSS example and this worked fine.  Loading from an external CSS file works as expected.